# Run python Flask API on AWS EC2 through boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm new at AWS, so I'm building a code to create a instance from an Image and I want that at the same time that this EC2 is created it run a pyhton code like this:

```
python /folder/folder2/api_flask.py
```

Here's my code on boto to create my instance.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.session('ec2')
client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-id_number_of_img', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.nano')
```

Thnks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

[run_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances) has an option called `UserData` which allows you to [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Thus to run your code, you can try to the following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2') # not boto3.session('ec2')

client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-id_number_of_img', 
                     MinCount=1, 
                     MaxCount=1, 
                     InstanceType='t2.nano',
                     UserData='#!/bin/bash\npython /folder/folder2/api_flask.py\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you are new to AWS, consider using CloudFormation for provisioning AWS Infrastructure. You'll still need leverage `UserData` as Marcin mentioned.

```
MyInstance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        python /folder/folder2/api_flask.py
    InstanceType: t2.nano
    ImageId: ami-id_number_of_img
```

Why CloudFormation? It'd be more readable, an allows for in-place updates as well as tear downs. You could then launch the stack via boto3 (disclaimer: not tested, but demonstrates the idea):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
with open('mytemplate.yml', 'r') as f:
  response = client.create_stack(
    StackName='my-stack',
    TemplateBody=f.read())
```